# JS Error on Script to Put Text in Upper Case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following js on my page:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByName("region").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("region");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
```

I have a field in a form as follows as well (the below I cannot edit as so I cannot append a js event to the input field):

```
<input type="text" id="region" placeholder="State/Province" name="region" value="" class="form-control">
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByName(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at (index):411
```

Can someone point me re this please?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you meant `document.getElementByName("region")` (Element not Elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getElementsByName` function returns a `nodeList`, not a single `node`, so it doesn't have an `addEventListener` function.

You should loop through the nodes, and call the function on each node

```
document.getElementsByName("region").forEach(function(node) {
   node.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how I can do that please?

Comment: Can you also let me know on how to set a var equal to the value in that input (as I need to add some additional stuff) please :) ?

Comment: What do you mean? Not quite sure what you want to achieve

Comment: I have changed to the following: function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("region") == "Ohio") {
        window.location = 'page3.html';
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Try again!");
    }  
    return false;
}